# Jquery show hide not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<div class="content" id="current">
    <div id="loader" style="display:none;"><img src="/images/loader.gif" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

I have this code. Above, which is a Box, and on submitting a button, I want a loader image there then when i get the response back, i want the image that s in the response to fadeIn.

When i click submit, I dont see the loader and I dont see the image replacing into #current.

```
    $('#Submit').click(function (e) {
         $('#error').html("");

         e.preventDefault();
         code = $('#Code').val(),

         $('#loader').show();
         $.post('/home/foo/', { code: code },
              function (data) {

                  $('#loader').hide();
                  alert(currentItem.ItemImage);
                  $('#current').html(currentItem.ItemImage);
```

How can i fix this?

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: no i look at error console. no error.

Comment: put a `console.log("response", data);` into the post callback function. See if it gets you something.

Comment: yes, i get back what i want. i dont have problem with that. `$('#loader').show();` doesnt work, even if i take it out from click.

Comment: How about console.log `#loader` before `hide` it, and see if it's visible ?

Comment: there is no form. that s why. and it works.

Comment: turns out in css. .content img is display: none;. sorry!

Comment: You might want to post that as your answer or delete this question before someone downvotes you ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking you need a semicolon after this line, not a comma:

```
code = $('#Code').val(),
```

to

```
code = $('#Code').val();
```

Comment: if i take the #loader div out of #content div, then loader shows. otherwise it doesnt

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that within css `.content img {display: none}` was causing loader not to show.